# Wifi list empty in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

After fixing the wifi problem in windows 10 using command prompt, there was a yellow triangle on the wifi icon. When I restarted the laptop and checked the wifi list, It was empty. I mean, I had switched on the Internet and hotpot an it was working, but, their was nothing on my wifi list... My laptop hadn't discovered any wifi networks, even though I had switched on the internet and hotpot on my mobile...  Please tell me what I gotta do???

Comment: "After fixing the wifi problem in windows 10 using command prompt" What exactly did you do?

Comment: Well, To fix the wifi problem? Firstly I opened command prompt and then wrote- reg delete HKCR\CLSID\{988248f3-a1ad-49bf-9170-676cbbc36ba3} /va /f               and then entered. After that I again wrote netcfg -v -u dni_dne     and then entered again. After this I restarted the computer and the wifirst icon was there, but the list was empty.... In the sense, The mobile hotspot and data pack was open but the computer hadn't discovered anything

Answer (score 0):

First check the wireless network adapter and driver status in device manager. Airplane mode should be switch off.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd>.
2. Choose "Services" page
3. Go down on the panel and click "Open services".
4. Click on "Name" column
5. Find `Radio Management Service` (tip: type `R`).
6. Right click on it, then choose `Properties`
7. Choose "General" page in the window
8. Find "Startup type" line.
9. Choose "Automatic" in the drop down menu.
10. Find "Service status" right under it.
11. Click on "Start".
12. Click on "Apply".
13. Close all of the windows. Done.

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily connect to wifi, create a new admin user, login and then see if you can browse wireless networks. If you can't, your wifi may be switched off via hardware. If you can browse and connect then it's windows or driver issue. The network will stay connected if you log out then back in as the normal user.